# Find the matrix of the orthogonal projection in R2 onto the line x=−2y.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the matrix of the orthogonal projection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto the line $x=−2y$.

If I had to decompose this matrix into a rotation projection rotation matrix, do I first start with the negative rotation of the angle made by the line $y=-x/2$ (call it -theta), then project down the $x$ axis, and then rotate by $\theta$ again? So the order would be T(theta)T(projection on $x$ axis)$T(-\theta)$

Comment: Do you have to do it that way? Often textbooks provide an algorithm for computing the orthogonal projection onto the column space of a matrix. If you are in that position, you could just find a matrix $A$ with linearly independent columns having $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x + 2y = 0\}$ as its column space, and use the algorithm. Another way would be to identify the orthogonal projections of the two standard basis vectors (via vector-specific, not fully-matrix-specific analysis) and make them the columns of a matrix. I say this because these approaches generalize and do not need visualization.

Comment: yeah i have to do it this way and not use the projection matrix directly. i just want to make sure im getting my order correct whether its negative theta first or do I rotate theta first?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what mean by "rotating negatively", or even which angle you're measuring as $\theta$. Let's see if I can make this clear.

Note that the $x$-axis and the line $y = -x/2$ intersect at the origin, and form an acute angle in the fourth quadrant. Let's call this angle $\theta \in [0, \pi]$.

You start the process by rotating the picture **counter-clockwise** by $\theta$. This will rotate the line $y = -x/2$ onto the $x$ axis. If you were projecting a point $p$ onto this line, you have now rotated it to a point $R_\theta p$, where
$$R_\theta = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Next, you project this point $R_\theta p$ onto the $x$-axis. The projection matrix is
$$P_x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
giving us the point $P_x R_\theta p$.

Finally, you rotate the picture **clockwise** by $\theta$. This is the inverse process to rotating counter-clockwise, and the corresponding matrix is $R_\theta^{-1} = R_\theta^\top = R_{-\theta}$. So, all in all, we get
$$R_{-\theta} P_x R_\theta p = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{pmatrix}p.$$